# In ProviderRepository.php line 208: Class 'Netshell\Paypal\PaypalServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel, docker, paypal, docker-compose

Hi Getting below exception when configuring laravel project into docker and trying to compose

```
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi

In ProviderRepository.php line 208:

  Class 'Netshell\Paypal\PaypalServiceProvider' not found


Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Command:

```
docker-compose exec app composer install
```

Compose.json:
I have below configurations in my file, is this something needs to be changed or upgraded.
Also i think are some configurations are deprecated? Please help!

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
    "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
    "license": "MIT",
    "type": "project",
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.3",
        "anandsiddharth/laravel-paytm-wallet": "^1.0",
        "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.2",
        "cinetpay/cinetpay-php": "^1.9",
        "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
        "gabrielbull/ups-api": "^0.8.0",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.0",
        "instamojo/instamojo-php": "^0.4.0",
        "iyzico/iyzipay-php": "^2.0",
        "kingflamez/laravelrave": "^2.0",
        "laracasts/flash": "^3.0",
        "laravel/framework": "6.*",
        "laravel/passport": "^7.3",
        "laravel/socialite": "^4.3",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "lcobucci/jwt": "3.3.3",
        "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
        "ext-ctype": "*",
        "ext-dom": "*",
        "ext-gd": "*",
        "ext-iconv": "*",
        "ext-fileinfo": "*",
        "ext-libxml": "*",
        "ext-mbstring": "*",
        "ext-SimpleXML": "*",
        "ext-xml": "*",
        "ext-xmlreader": "*",
        "ext-xmlwriter": "*",
        "ext-zip": "*",
        "ext-zlib": "*",
        "phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.9",
        "maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
        "mehedi-iitdu/core-component-repository": "dev-master",
        "nexmo/laravel": "^2.2",
        "osenco/mpesa": "^1.20",
        "razorpay/razorpay": "2.0.0",
        "spatie/db-dumper": "dev-master",
        "spatie/laravel-image-optimizer": "^1.3",
        "stripe/stripe-php": "^6.29",
        "twilio/sdk": "^6.1",
        "unicodeveloper/laravel-paystack": "^1.0"
    },
    ....
}
```

Comment: It seems like you have an outdated autoload.php file. delete vendor folder and run composer install again or run `composer remove netshell/paypal`

Comment: @RavishaHesh Yes. i did removed vendors and ran cmd: composer remove netshell/paypal which installed all other components and says  Class 'Netshell\Paypal\PaypalServiceProvider' not found

Comment: I don't see that package in your composer.json file that's why I have asked you to remove it. If you have `Netshell\Paypal\PaypalServiceProvider` in config/app.php remove from that also. then if required add it again via composer require. since you are using laravel 6 you don't have to manually register providers

Answer (score 0):

Do you register

```
Netshell\Paypal\PaypalServiceProvider
```

in your config/app.php?

Comment: yes i do have Netshell\Paypal\PaypalServiceProvider::class, under config/app.php